# OnMouseOver Background color in listview items .Net MAUI

Tags: listview, .net-core, maui

how can I change the background color in a ListView in .Net MAUI when I move the mouse over a ListView item? I have this code....

```
<ListView x:Name="lvWords"  ZIndex="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" Margin="10,0,0,0" SeparatorColor="Red" BackgroundColor="Transparent" RowHeight="25">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Word}"  TextColor="White" />
                
            </DataTemplate>
            
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.SelectedItem   >
           
           
        </ListView.SelectedItem>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add PointerOver VisualState to Label:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
          <Label Text="{Binding Word}">
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <VisualStateGroupList>
                     <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                         <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                        Value="Blue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                         </VisualState>
                         <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" 
                                        Value="white" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                         </VisualState>
                     </VisualStateGroup>
                  </VisualStateGroupList>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          </Label>
       </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

When you move the mouse over a ListView item, it can change the background color in a ListView in .Net MAUI.